# How to compare a single character from url request parameter in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-namespace

I am reading the url parameter which has a single character. It will either be `Y` or `N`. I have to write a condition to check if it `Y` or `N` and do something accordingly. This is what I wrote but does not seem to work (always goes to else). The url is

http://wwww.helloworld.com/showInfo?thecountry=us&theconditionTypeInUrl=Y

```
  <s:set var="theUrl" value="%{#parameters.theconditionTypeInUrl}" />
  <s:if test="%{#theUrl == 'Y'}">

  </s:if>
  <s:else>

  </s:else>
```

I also tried

```
 <s:set var="theUrl" value='%{#parameters.theconditionTypeInUrl}' />

  <s:if test='%{#theUrl == "Y"}'>

 </s:if>
 <s:else>

 </s:else>
```

the struts.xml contains

```
<action name="showInfo" class="showInfoAction">
   <result name="success" type="tiles">dis.Info</result>
   <result name="no_results" type="tiles">dis.noInfo</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Post the `struts.xml`.

Comment: try using <s:set var="theUrl" value="#parameters.theconditionTypeInUrl" />, also make sure params interceptor is configured in your default interceptor stack

Comment: What is that I should configure in params intercetor. Please explain. I am knew to struts2.

Comment: Parameters accessed this way are in an array. Did you consider checking the type of the value in the parameter value as part of the debugging process?!

Answer (score 0):

Usually request parameters are processed by the `params` interceptor. The action configuration should have this interceptor included in the stack. If you not referencing this interceptor explicitly the `defaultStack` is used that already contains the `params` interceptor. What you need is the package for the action to be extended the `"struts-default"`.

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Then parameters will be processed and put to the action attributes, where you could access them via OGNL by implementing getter and setter.

Another way is to implement [`ParameterAware` interface](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ParameterAware.html) by your action. After injecting parameters it could be available from the action that is on top of the `valueStack` and you could get parameters via

```
<s:if test="parameters['theconditionTypeInUrl'] == 'Y'">
```

after adding getter for parameters attribute

```
Map getParameters(){
  return this.parameters;
}
```

More detail explanation you could find [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14182#content/view/13977).

The way you are trying access request parameters from the action context map via OGNL using `#parameters` key. There could be troubles accessing parameters in the `if` tag, see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/86810).