# Struts2 equivalent for <bean:parameter> tag

Tags: struts2

What is the equivalent in Struts2 for  tag:

```jsp
<bean:parameter id="myId" name="name"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <bean:parameter>
> ```
>
> Define a scripting variable based on the value(s) of the specified
>   request parameter.

You don't need scripting variables in JSP. Request parameters available to OGNL or JSP EL expression engines. You can use either of them (where it's applicable) to retrieve parameters. Learn more about `ParameterAware` interface which allows you to inject parameters to the action. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001858/573032) answer will help you in this direction.

Also if you have action properties that can be populated (have setters for parameter names) then it's done automatically by `params` interceptor. It also applies type conversions to convert parameter values to the corresponding data type.