# Testing Struts request parameter against String with odd results - why does it look like a collection?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am calling an action via `foo.action?error=bar`

In `struts.xml`, I have configured the action chain as follows:

```
<action name="foo">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
  <!-- custom interceptors -->
  <result name="success">/jsp/foo.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In the JSP, I'm running a test:

```
<s:if test="#parameters.error[0] == 'bar'">
```

It's legacy code; this works.
However, the following does not, and I don't understand why:

```
<s:if test="#parameters.error == 'bar'">
```

Why do I need to pretend the error parameter is a collection?

Judging from the docs:

- [Access to ValueStack from JSPs](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/access-to-valuestack-from-jsps.html)
- [JSP](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/jsp.html)

I shouldn't have to - but then I haven't used JSPs much...

I have added the following to the JSP, in order to help me understand what's going on:

```
<s:property value="#parameters.error"/>                          // bar
<s:property value="parameters.error"/>                           // <nothing>
<s:property value="parameters.error[0]"/>                        // <nothing>
<%= pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("error") %>            // bar
<%= pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("error").getClass() %> // class java.lang.String
<s:property value="#parameters.error=='bar'"/>                   // false
<s:property value="'token'.getClass()"/>                         // <nothing>
```

That output confuses me even more. Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Take a look at the following url - `blah?some=v1&some=v2&some=v3&another=v`. Parameters is a map of list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pretend, it's a collection. The new implementation uses `HttpParameters` and OGNL expression doesn't know that, a tag is using `toString()` value on object that is not a string.

You can read more about parameters in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45300007/573032) answer.

[`HttpParameters`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/HttpParameters.html).  The later class implements a `Map<String,Parameter>`, so you can use
this to get/put parameters to the map.

**Also see:**

- [How can we access request parameters passed into an Action](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14182#content/view/13977)
- [How to use parameters in JSP](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/jsp#request-parameter)

Comment: How would you then get the first map element? `<s:if test="#parameters.error[0] == 'bar'">` works, but `<s:property value="parameters.error[0]"/>` doesn't, but both are tags...?

Comment: Just looked at ["What's the difference between # , % and $ signs in Struts tags?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/2018047) and realised I might have to force evaluation as OGNL, and indeed, it appears to work: `<s:property value="%{#parameters.error[0]}"/>`

Comment: This is an old post, it might not applicable to the new version. To have an explicit explanation of your problem I'd recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001858/573032 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986848/573032

Comment: Your answer goes into detail about `HttpParameters` implementing `Map<String, Parameter>` - which doesn't answer why what looks like an array indexation was needed. Your post contains useful hints, but in 2017, when I asked my question, it wasn't the answer. (`Parameter` also doesn't seem to implement `Collection`.) What did help was the link I subsequently dug out myself and left as a comment. So, thanks for your reminder what an Accepted Answer is, but your replies, helpful as they were, weren't the answer I was looking for - which is why I didn't accept yours back then. :)